Android RecyclerView not displaying data from SQLite database using custom Adapter
Problem Description:
I'm developing an Android app using Android Studio and Java. The app is designed to display worker information using a RecyclerView within a fragment (constructorsFragment). I've implemented a SQLite database (workerDBHelper) to store worker data and a custom Adapter (WorkerAdapter) to bind the data to the RecyclerView's card views (custom_cardview.xml). However, I'm facing an issue where the card views are not displaying any data from the database when the app runs.
Code Snippets:

workerDBHelper.java (Database Helper Class):

// Relevant code for database creation and data insertion
   // Example code for inserting data:
   long newRowId = db.insert(TABLE_WORKERS, null, values);



Worker.java (Worker Class):

// Relevant code for defining Worker attributes
   // Example code for getters and setters:
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }



WorkerAdapter.java (Custom Adapter Class):

// Relevant code for binding data to ViewHolder
   // Example code for onBindViewHolder() method:
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WorkerViewHolder holder, int position) {
       Worker worker = workerList.get(position);
       holder.bind(worker);
   }



constructorsFragment.java (Fragment Class):

// Relevant code for fetching data from the database and setting up RecyclerView
   // Example code for fetchWorkersFromDatabase() method:
   private void fetchWorkersFromDatabase() {
       List<Worker> fetchedWorkers = dbHelper.getAllWorkers();
       workerList.clear();
       workerList.addAll(fetchedWorkers);
       workerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }


Issue Details:

The constructorsFragment should display card views containing worker information fetched from the SQLite database.
The fetchWorkersFromDatabase() method is called to retrieve data from the database and update the workerList.
Despite fetching data successfully from the database, the RecyclerView within constructorsFragment remains empty, indicating that the card views are not being populated with the fetched worker data.

Expected Outcome:
I expect the RecyclerView in the constructorsFragment to display card views containing worker information fetched from the SQLite database. Each card view should show attributes such as the worker's name, job, rating, price range, etc., as per the data retrieved from the database.
Additional Notes:

I've ensured that the database contains valid worker data and that the workerDBHelper class is functioning correctly to fetch data.
The layout files (custom_cardview.xml) and the custom Adapter (WorkerAdapter) have been implemented following standard practices for RecyclerView and data binding.

Question:
What could be causing the RecyclerView in constructorsFragment not to display the card views with worker data fetched from the SQLite database? Is there anything missing or incorrect in the code provided?

Implemented RecyclerView in constructorsFragment:

Expected Outcome: The RecyclerView should display card views containing worker information fetched from the SQLite database.
Actual Outcome: The RecyclerView remains empty; card views are not populated with worker data.


Created workerDBHelper for database operations:

Expected Outcome: The workerDBHelper class should successfully fetch worker data from the SQLite database.
Actual Outcome: Data is fetched from the database without errors; however, the RecyclerView does not display the fetched data.


Defined Worker class for worker information:

Expected Outcome: The Worker class should encapsulate worker attributes and allow for easy data retrieval and binding.
Actual Outcome: Worker attributes are properly defined, and data retrieval is successful, but the RecyclerView does not show the data.


Implemented WorkerAdapter for RecyclerView:

Expected Outcome: The WorkerAdapter should bind worker data to ViewHolder views and display them in card views.
Actual Outcome: Data binding is implemented correctly, but the RecyclerView does not display any card views with worker data.


Initialized RecyclerView and WorkerAdapter in constructorsFragment:

Expected Outcome: Upon initialization, the RecyclerView and WorkerAdapter should fetch worker data and display card views.
Actual Outcome: Initialization is successful, but the RecyclerView remains empty, indicating a problem with data binding or display.


Called fetchWorkersFromDatabase() in constructorsFragment:

Expected Outcome: The fetchWorkersFromDatabase() method should populate the workerList and notify the adapter of data changes.
Actual Outcome: Data is fetched from the database and added to the workerList, but the RecyclerView does not update with the fetched data.


Ensured layout files and custom Adapter are correctly implemented:

Expected Outcome: The custom card view layout (custom_cardview.xml) and the WorkerAdapter should work together to display worker data.
Actual Outcome: Layout files and the custom Adapter are implemented correctly, but the RecyclerView does not display worker data.


Checked database content and dbHelper functionality:

Expected Outcome: The database contains valid worker data, and the dbHelper class functions correctly to fetch data.
Actual Outcome: Database content is valid, dbHelper fetches data without errors, but the RecyclerView does not show the fetched data.


Verified WorkerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged():

Expected Outcome: Calling notifyDataSetChanged() should update the RecyclerView with the fetched data.
Actual Outcome: Data changes are notified to the adapter, but the RecyclerView remains empty.


Considered error handling and exceptions:

Expected Outcome: Proper error handling should catch any exceptions or issues related to data fetching or binding.
Actual Outcome: No errors or exceptions are reported, but the RecyclerView does not display worker data.




Too much text; is that a 10 item list of questions or requirements you want us to address? Then it's way too big for stackoverflow; check the [tour]. Limit yourself to one problem per question and do include a [mcve].
